# Accidentally double cashed a check

Tags: check

I got a check for my rent for Jan 2021. I bank with Chime and I went to do a mobile deposit on 01/02/21. It said the funds wouldn't be available until 01/04/21 so I cancelled the deposit and just cashed the check at Walmart, as I needed it immediately.

Yesterday, 01/04/21, I noticed that the check had been deposited into my account on Chime anyways. I immediately contacted Chime, tried to by phone didn't get a live person so they told me to use the chat feature in the app and to email, so I sent a chat request yesterday 01/04/21 and an email as well.   I also sent chime an email this morning 01/05/21 so that I could return the money to Chime and fix the issue, but no response.

What will happen if the check bounces at Walmart before I can resolve the issue with Chime? I had no intentions of double cashing and don't want to get into trouble.

Comment: Perhaps quickly contact WalMart ??

Comment: Talk to whoever who **issued** the check; maybe it won't bounce.  (Also, this is why using a bank with a local branch is so useful: you can go to a teller and straighten things out.)

Comment: This seems like a use-case any decent app design should take into account. Are the numbers on the bottom of the check unique, which enables Chime to detect a duplicate?